# Trying to use selenium on raspberry Pi with chrome python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use selenium on my raspberry pi which is connect to a monitor for my arlo camera but the code did not work on the raspberry pi. Although I have tested the code on my windows machine and it was working. I am able to run the chrome driver on the raspberry pi but problem will come when I try to configure chromeoption. I got an error that I am not able to understand. Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver') 
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

chrome_options = Options()
prefs = {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins": 1,
    "profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist-flash-player": 1,
    "profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player": 1,
    "PluginsAllowedForUrls": "https://arlo.netgear.com/#/login"

    }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("--kiosk") # full screen


self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://arlo.netgear.com/#/login')
'''
my username and password for accessing arlo website
'''
username = driver.find_element_by_id('userId')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
username.send_keys('enter your user name here')
password.send_keys('password ')

driver.find_element_by_id('loginButton').click()
```

This is the error tracback:

```
 =================== RESTART: /home/pi/arloOpner/chrome.py ===================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/arloOpner/chrome.py", line 20, in <module>
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1282, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
>>>
```

Comment: Have you tried running without the some or all of the options on the pi?

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 yes I did and it works, but I need this option to enable flash player

Comment: Maybe try a different broswer - firefox, phantomjs etc. And does the website work if you go to it manually?

Comment: Right now I trying to use firefox. yes, the website works manually.@ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000

Comment: Maybe try using this chromedriver for ARM: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/armhf/chromium-driver/download